# how to upgrade SUSE form the iso file using ansible

Tags: ansible, suse

I have the requirement to upgrade(patching) the new major version of SUSE using ansible playbook

I tried using different module of ansible but couldnt find the steps

Comment: We encourage all users on SO to post their effort, so kindly do post the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: we nee to install the new version like from"SLES-11-SP3-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso" to "SLES-11-SP4-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso " . we can mount it with the Ansible mount module . but I need help in the next step to install it (upgrade to newer version) with the ansible . I see the admin team is doing with the yast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution for it:

**steps:**

1. mount nfs point ( where you will store the ISO file)
2. Using Ansible to copy the file to target machine ( host)
3. Create repository form that ISO in the target machine ( I have used shell module for it with zypper command)
4. upgrade distribution with the repo in the previous step.

thats all :)

Answer (score -1):

from [zypper – Manage packages on SUSE and openSUSE](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/zypper_module.html)

```
# Update all packages
- zypper:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
```

but i guess you need extra steps before, like updating the central repo, or mount the iso on hosts, etc...

Comment: i get a -1 for this ?

Comment: the above command does all update. what if u upload and mount an iso and then install the new version like from"SLES-11-SP3-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso"    to   "SLES-11-SP4-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso " . we can mount it with the Ansible mount module . but I need help in the next step to install it (upgrade to newer version) with the ansible . I see the admin team is doing with the yast

Comment: Look procedure here : Update via using a SLE 11 SP4 installation media https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7016711 , but i don't think you will be able to automate this with ansible :/